# Adding multiple softmax classifiers to TensorFlow example

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, classification, multilabel-classification, softmax

I am starting with the generic TensorFlow example.

To classify my data I need to use multiple labels (ideally multiple `softmax` classifiers) on the final layer, because my data carries multiple independent labels (sum of probabilities is not 1).

Specifically in the `retrain.py` these lines in `add_final_training_ops()` add the final tensor

```
final_tensor = tf.nn.softmax(logits, name=final_tensor_name)
```

and here

```
cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
      logits, ground_truth_input)
```

Is there already a generic classifier in TensorFlow? If not, how to achieve multilevel classification?

`add_final_training_ops()` from `tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py`:

```
def add_final_training_ops(class_count, final_tensor_name, bottleneck_tensor):

  with tf.name_scope('input'):
    bottleneck_input = tf.placeholder_with_default(
        bottleneck_tensor, shape=[None, BOTTLENECK_TENSOR_SIZE],
        name='BottleneckInputPlaceholder')

    ground_truth_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,
                                        [None, class_count],
                                        name='GroundTruthInput')

  layer_name = 'final_training_ops'
  with tf.name_scope(layer_name):
    with tf.name_scope('weights'):
      layer_weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([BOTTLENECK_TENSOR_SIZE, class_count], stddev=0.001), name='final_weights')
      variable_summaries(layer_weights)
    with tf.name_scope('biases'):
      layer_biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([class_count]), name='final_biases')
      variable_summaries(layer_biases)
    with tf.name_scope('Wx_plus_b'):
      logits = tf.matmul(bottleneck_input, layer_weights) + layer_biases
      tf.summary.histogram('pre_activations', logits)

  final_tensor = tf.nn.softmax(logits, name=final_tensor_name)
  tf.summary.histogram('activations', final_tensor)

  with tf.name_scope('cross_entropy'):
    cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
      logits, ground_truth_input)
    with tf.name_scope('total'):
      cross_entropy_mean = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)
  tf.summary.scalar('cross_entropy', cross_entropy_mean)

  with tf.name_scope('train'):
    train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(FLAGS.learning_rate).minimize(
        cross_entropy_mean)

  return (train_step, cross_entropy_mean, bottleneck_input, ground_truth_input,
          final_tensor)
```

Even after adding the `sigmoid` classifier and retraining, Tensorboard still shows `softmax`:

[image: Tensorboard with softmax]

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow has [`tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/nn.html#sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits) for independent, multilabel classification.

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work. I tried retraining the model and they output is still `softmax` kind. Tensorboard also keeps showing `softmax` in the graph (see screenshot)